# Where is clicking noise coming from in kitchen

Tags: electrical, kitchens, noise

We have an intermittent click somewhere in the kitchen. We are not sure if it is coming from an appliance or from a possible electrical problem. All appliances are electric and 2 Years old. The sound is a quick click. Then maybe a few minutes later another click. Then maybe 2 hours later another click. It happens when appliances are in use or not in use. Breakers are not tripped. We thought maybe the stove only because we have replaced the light in the oven 3 times in 2 years. I also have a scratch/crack on one of the smooth top burners. And it seems to happen maybe?? after stove or oven have been used. Don't know whether to call an electrician or appliance repair person. We also replaced the 2 gfci in the kitchen.

Why would this start all of a sudden? It never did it until about a month ago.

Comment: Can you pin down what's making the clicking at least?

Comment: I have set in the kitchen just hoping to find where it's coming from but no luck.

Comment: `Don't know whether to call an electrician or appliance repair person` ... and what would you ask them to repair?

Comment: Unplug all appliances from the wall and see if the clicking continues. That will eliminate or prove one possibility. If there's no more clicking, then the problem is an appliance. Plug them in, one-by-one, listening for the clicks. If you plug in the fridge and no clicks for 2-3 hours (if you don't open the fridge, it'll keep food cold for many, many hours w/o power), it's probably not that, add the oven. If you start hearing the clicking, it's either the oven or the _combination_, so unplug the fridge & listen. Continue with slow, steady testing until you find the source.

Comment: @Judy Its been 9 months - did you find anything ?

Comment: @Judy Is there anything made of wood in the kitchen? I'm wondering if it could be woodworm making the noise.

Comment: I would suspect the refrigerator, especially if it has an ice maker.

Answer (score 1):

Pipes expanding and contracting with changes in temperature can make noises. Hot water pipes in particular heat up and cool down regularly.

Comment: And, stove elements (as she mentioned) will expand and contract when heating and cooling.

Comment: My ice maker makes a bunch of random sounds at times. Also do you have an instant hot water dispenser? That might be cycling (normal) and be expansion ticks or relay noise.

Comment: I understand that elements or pipes can make noise when expanding or contracting.  But why would this start all of a sudden? It never did it until about a month ago.

Comment: ...but you did not share **that** detail in your question. I'm not physic, so I only knw what you have shared about your problem. More details may lead to better speculation.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely cause is a jug for boiling water . Some just click turn it off at the wall when not in use.

Comment: A "jug for boiling water"? "turn it off at the wall"? I'd guess you were British (I believe many of their outlets can be turned off with a switch), but they would call it a "kettle". So, care to [edit] your answer to expand on what these statements mean and give some sort of indication as to _why_ you think this is the cause?

Answer (score -2):

You have two or three different appliances on one circuit and there fighting with each other and the noise is coming from either the Washer or dryer and you most likely have a furnace on the same circuit that is causing this problem. I have the same problem and it's my washer making the noise, a clicking noise, it's a new state of the art new washer and it doesn't like the old units on the same circuit. I have not found how to fit it but I'm sure they must have a plugin that will stop this.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The noise has. stopped now that the weather has cooled down. It did that last year too and we thought it was gone and it started again when it warmed up and lasted all summer. Very strange.